# URL Structure needs modification in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, canonical-link

I have a website i.e. [www.exhibitionsnow.com](http://www.exhibitionsnow.com), it's URL structure is not good. I am new to ASP.NET. Can someone suggest the correct procedure to rewrite the URLs, and also what would be the code to apply a canonical URL.

Answer (score 0):

URL Rewriting module **EXISTS** for IIS, it's very simple to use, if you don't need (I'm sure you don't) dynamic URL rewriting.

[check this link](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module)

Answer (score 0):

There is an article about [URL Rewriting](http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/). You can simply apply this to your web site